# Proof that $\mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{N}\cong \mathbb{N}$ without $AC_\omega$ or Arithmetic

Tags: set-theory, axiom-of-choice

Proving that $\mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{N} \cong \mathbb{N}$ is incredibly useful for proving that the countable union of countable sets is countable and the fact that finite cartesian products of countable sets are countable.

Traditional proofs of this use Cantor's Pairing function, either using $(n,m)\mapsto 2^n3^m$ to give an injection (which is enough using Cantor-Schroeder-Bernstein Theorem or that an infinite subset of a countable set is countable; note I am by no means implying that either of these require any form of AC) or by giving an actual bijection via the map $(n,m)\mapsto \frac{(n+m)(n+m+1)}{2}+m$.

Another proof approach is to use the 'Countability Lemma' that given a function $f:X\rightarrow \omega$ such that every fiber $f^{-1}(n)$ is finite, then $X$ is countable.  However, the proof ([here](http://dspace.bracu.ac.bd/bitstream/handle/10361/523/Vol%201%20No%202.14.pdf?sequence=1)) both implicitly uses the Axiom of Countable Choice and more arithmetic than I would like (to actually define the bijection outlined).  I should point out that the choice used in the proof is that it chooses for each natural number $n$ a bijection from $n$ to $f^{-1}(n)$.

**What I am looking for is a proof that $\mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{N}\cong \mathbb{N}$ without the use of either $AC_\omega$ or any arithmetic.**

Arithmetic that is as simple as the addition of two natural numbers is okay, since it can be easily shown to correspond to $n+m := \left| n\coprod m \right|$.  A less trivial example of something that is 'okay' is the fact that there are a finite number of pairs $(n,m)$ that add up to a given number.  However, have as little arithmetic as possible is a plus; some examples of things that are too much include factoring or any mention of the rationals or reals (e.g. no floor or ceiling function).  The point is base the bijection only on the properties of $\omega$ as the minimal inductive set and the properties that follow immediately from this.

$AC_\omega$ is certainly not required to show that $\mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{N}\cong \mathbb{N}$ is true, nor should arithmetic on $\mathbb{N}$ be necessary to define such a bijection (though clearly it simplifies things).

As a final note, I am using 'countable' to mean in bijection with $\omega$.

Comment: You could use what Jech (p. 30) calls the canonical well-ordering of $\omega\times\omega$ to get a bijection with $\omega$. This doesn't require any arithmetic.

Comment: It is unlikely that $AC_\omega$ is required in the proof you linked *when it is applied to* $\mathbb{N}$. There is a canonical well ordering of $\mathbb{N}$ and thus of every finite subset of $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: @CarlMummert I was under the impression that in order to well-order each of the fibers $f^{-1}(n)$ (so that we can meaningfully make the sequence $A_{k(n-1)+1},A_{k(n-1)+2},\ldots, A_{k(n-1)+k(n)}$) I needed to pick a bijection for each $n$.  I imagined that it used $AC_\omega$ in the same way that $AC_\omega$ is used in the proof that the countable union of countable sets is countable, in which a bijection is picked for each element of the countable family.

Comment: When we are talking about $\omega \times \omega$, it is already in bijection with the ordinal $\omega \cdot \omega$, which is well ordered, so that gives a canonical well ordering of every finite subset (in fact every subset) of $\omega \times \omega$.

Comment: @GME You're right, this does provide a proof. For some reason I falsely thought that it required AC.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can define a sequence $A_n$ of subsets of $\omega $ ($=\mathbb{N}$) by recursion.
$A_0 = \{ 2n : n \in \omega\}$ and similarly $A_{i+1}$ is "every other" element of $\omega \setminus A_i$.  To be more direct, we define that $n \in A_j$ if and only if there is a sequence of functions $(f_0, \ldots, f_j)$ from $\omega$ to $\omega$ such that $n$ is in the range of $f_j$, $f_0$ enumerates "every other" element of $\omega$, and for all $k < j$, $f_{k+1}$ enumerates "every other" element of $\omega \setminus \operatorname{range}f_k$.

Here we say that a function $f$ enumerates "every other" element of an infinite $X \subseteq \omega$ if $f$ is increasing, $f(0) = \min X$ and, for all $i$, there is exactly one element of $X$ between $f(i)$ and $f(i+1)$. Notice that arithmetic whatsoever is required in that definition; it is purely order theoretic.

Now we can prove, again without any arithmetic, that $\omega$ is the disjoint union of $\langle A_i : i \in \omega\rangle$. In particular, each $k$ is either in $A_k$ or in $A_j$ for some $j < k$.

Thus there is a function $f$ such that $f(n) = (i,j)$ exactly when $n$ is the $j$th element of $A_i$.  This is the desired bijection between $\omega$ and $\omega \times \omega$.

Comment: That is an interesting methodology.  I've never seen the definition of a function 'enumerating "every other" element of an infinite subset of $\omega$' before.  The terminology of "every other" seems easily confusable with the complement on a first read-through.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, the Cantor-Bernstein theorem does not require the axiom of choice at all. So it satisfies your requirement (it uses nor $\sf AC_\omega$, nor arithmetic).

Secondly, the Cantor pairing function does not rely on a lot of arithmetic.

Thirdly, you can use the following bijection $(n,m)\mapsto 2^n(2m+1)-1$. This, again, uses some arithmetic but not "a large amount".

Fourthly, if you know that $(m,n)\mapsto 2^n3^m$ is injective, and you know that every infinite subset of $\Bbb N$ is countable, then you have finished. To see that, note that if $A$ is an infinite subset of $\Bbb N$, $a\mapsto |\{b\in A\mid b<a\}|$ is a bijection as wanted.

There are other considerations too.

Comment: Oh, I didn't mean to imply that Cantor-Berstein used any form of AC; I only mentioned it to say that the injection was enough.  The reason that the function $(n,m)\mapsto 2^n3^m$ is something I wanted to avoid is that it encroached on Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic territory (in order to show injectivity).  Certainly its injectivity is weaker than Fund. Thm of Arithmetic, but for my purposes still uses too much arithmetic.  I suppose what I'm really looking for is a purely set-theoretic bijection.

Comment: I'll try and make my question more clear as far as how much arithmetic is okay.

Comment: I'm not quite sure that I understand your objection. If you have cardinal arithmetic, you have addition, multiplication and exponentiation. Moreover, you can prove that all the usual properties of arithmetic hold for them in the case of finite cardinals. These are set theoretic statements now. This is set theory. This is not arithmetic, it is cardinal arithmetic.

Comment: I suppose what I'm failing to see is how to prove a statement like "every non-zero finite cardinal can be written in a unique way as the product of a (finite) power of 2 and an odd finite cardinal" without the argument eventually descending into arithmetic.  I would imagine that it could presented in such a way that it only dealt with cardinals, but I don't see how it wouldn't just be calling equivalent things different names.

Comment: Using induction. Something which $\sf ZF$ proves regardless. If it is true for all $k<n$, then either $n$ cannot be written as the product of two cardinals $>1$ (it is prime or $1$), then we are done (either $n=2$ or $n$ is odd); otherwise $n=k\cdot m=2^{k_1}k_2\cdot2^{m_1}m_2=2^{k_1+m_1}(k_2m_2)$. Since $k_2$ and $m_2$ are both odd, their product is odd as well, and we're done.

Comment: I see what you mean, but to me that is simply arithmetic.  However, it is very simple, as you point out.  Thank you for the information.

Comment: If you say that cardinal (or ordinal) arithmetic are not set theoretic, then I'm not sure what to tell you. If you agree that cardinal and ordinal arithmetic are set theoretic in nature, then all arithmetic is yours for the taking.

Comment: I am not trying to say that cardinal arithmetic is not set theoretic, only that the distinction between finite cardinal arithmetic and (very) elementary number theory (working in the model of $\omega$) is very thin, so much so that I think the distinction is negligible.  However, more than likely I am just missing something and will stop wasting your time with imprecise conditions. XD

Comment: No, but that's the point. $\omega$, equipped with cardinal (or ordinal) arithmetic is exactly the natural numbers with the "number theoretic arithmetic" that we know. So using one is like using the other. There is **no** difference. Since we interpret the natural numbers inside set theory using definable arithmetic (cardinal or ordinal) then all the theorems about the natural numbers transfer automatically to $\omega$ with cardinal arithmetic.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, here it goes:

[image: Tessellation of NxN]

Obviously the blue dots are points of NxN and you get a bijection.

Comment: This is a traditional bijection, but actually writing down the rule of such a function is to as easy as drawing the picture.  If you can write it down in such a way that it doesn't use much arithmetic (and moreover that it can be shown to be bijective without much arithmetic), then I'll gladly accept.

Comment: Then I am not exactly sure what do you mean without "much" arithmetic. How hard must the "without much" be?

Comment: Preferably none, but adding is fine, for example.

Comment: So you *do* want an expression only involving addition at most? Is it ok to give two trivial injections?

Comment: As far as arithmetical operations go, only addition is allowed.  However, any set theoretic proof suffices, so long as it does not use the Axiom of Choice, since this would imply it easily.  What do you mean by trivial injections?

Comment: I mean if is it ok to give two injections, NxN -> N and N -> NxN or you want a pure bijection.

Comment: Yes, two injections would be alright, though only the injection $\mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{N}\rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ is necessary.

Comment: All the bijections I have seen or devised of this fact are either in the line of the drawing or in the one Asaf has stated. In the case of the drawing, the bijection expressed as a function is ugly and involves casuistic, but is easily written as a recursion.

Comment: I understand; this is the reason I came on here to ask the question.  Thanks for the help though!